# Why can't Ubuntu find the GIMP graphics editor theme files?

Tags: 20.04, gimp

The path to the theme files is specified in the GIMP graphics editor dialog box. I am attaching a screenshot. I wanted to tweak the theme a bit.

I enter the following command into the terminal: `cd /usr/share/gimp/`

And I get an error:
`No such file or directory`

Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you are using a snap or flatpak packaging of Gimp. Both types contain all their files in a virtual file system, so what they see as `/usr/share` is not the `/usr/share` of the file system.

If you use Gimp's file browser you will be able to navigate to and open `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/images/gimp-splash.png` because it is in the Snap/Flaptpak package.

This sandboxing is one of the reasons I stay away from these packages as much as possible.

if you want to tweak a theme, copy it from the [source tree](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/tree/gimp-2-10/themes) and add it to the `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes` (which should exist in your user space). You can then tweak it to your heart's content.